# Number of triples

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{1,2,\dots,2014\}$. Determine the number of triplets $(x,y,z)\in A \times A \times A$, with the property that $x<y<z$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression.
It's an interesting quesiton. More, if we have $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, how does the number of triples affect?

Comment: If it is interesting, what are your thoughts so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the constant difference $d=y-x=z-y$ is an interesting number associated to arithmetic progressions, so the idea to classify these progression by that difference should not be too surprising. Fixing $d$, you can easily check that there are $2013-2d$ associated progressions. So you are asking for
$$
  \sum_{d=1} ^{\lfloor\frac{2013}2\rfloor}(2013-2d)
$$
I think you can figure out how to compute that sum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $x<y<z$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression, then $y$ is uniquely determined by $x$ and $z$. Also, $z-x$ is necessarily even. So the number of such triplets is exactly the same as the number of pairs $x < z$ such that $z-x$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of numbers such that the difference between the consecutive terms is constant.  Hence $B=A+M, C=A+2M$ for some $M$ such that: $\exists M \in [1..\lfloor \frac{N}2\rfloor -1] : 0\leq A \leq N - 2M$

So, to count:
$C(N) $ $= \sum\limits_{M=1}^{\lfloor \frac{N}2-1\rfloor}\;\sum\limits_{A=1}^{N-2M} 1 \\= \sum\limits_{M=1}^{\lfloor \frac{N}2-1\rfloor} (N-2M) \\ = \left[NX -X(X+1)\right]_{X=\lfloor \frac{N}2\rfloor-1} \\ = \left(\lfloor \frac{N}2\rfloor -1\right)\left(\lceil \frac{N}2\rceil-2\right)$

$C(2014) = (1006)(1005) = 1,011,030$

Comment: I don't understand the 3-rd and 4-th line of your post.

Comment: Take the sum $\sum\limits_{M=1}^{X} N - 2 \sum\limits_{M=1}^{X} M = NX - X(X+1)$ and evaluate when $X=\lfloor \frac{N}{2}-1\rfloor$